# Suppose that $f:E \to \Bbb [0, +\infty]$ is integrable and $E_n =\{x \in E \mid f(x) < \frac1n \}$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E_n}f = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f:E \to \Bbb [0, +\infty]$ is integrable and $E_n =\{x \in E \mid f(x) <\frac1n \}$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E_n}f = 0$.

What I would like to say is that since the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \emptyset$ and the sets are decreasing then $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{E_n}f = \int_{\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n } f = \int_{\emptyset} f = 0$$ but is there this kind of property with the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Get the $E_n$ inside the integral and guess which theorem apply

Comment: You mean that $\int_{E_n} f = \int_{E} f \chi_{E_n}$?